# iTunes connect can't add the build to the external tester

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

in iTunes Connect, I can't add the build to the external tester 
and who make my app allow to test and change status for review?

Comment: Have you invited your internal tester to Test Flight?

Comment: yes and I need to invite external tester

Comment: Maybe the vacation of iTunes Connect does not allow to add new testers

Answer (score 0):

for now iTunes Connect Team are on vacation 
so wait until Dec 30

Comment: and also when i need to add build to external tester?